# How to access Search Record and set some field?

Tags: search, load, netsuite, record

I want to load a saved search , and set "inactive" field to true.
Problem is I tried to load it , but it failed

I tried this :

```
var searchRec = record.load({ type: search.Type.SAVED_SEARCH, id: result.id, isDynamic: false });
```

Also read the help on the N/search module but no answer.

Comment: You want to set the saved search to inactive, or the record?

Comment: Set the saved search inactive trom a suitescript (2.0).

Comment: Ah ok. I don’t believe you can do that from a script, unfortunately. That said, I have not tried (and can’t at the moment). If you are ok with deleting, you could try a mass delete script. Outside of that, there are permissions you can set to minimize creation of saved searches, which may help you in the future.